# Path of current template file within Velocity

Tags: velocity, templating

Suppose I have the following templates:

1. .../main.vm
2. .../sections/footer.vm

Suppose main.vm looks like this:

```
Hello world, this is the main template, it's name is $name
This template also has the following footer:
#parse("sections/footer.vm")
```

And suppose footer.vm looks like this:

```
Hi there, I'm the footer! My file name is $name!
```

I would like for $name in main.vm to be "main.vm", and $name in footer.vm to be "sections/footer.vm". Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless you override the behavior of `#parse`, or provide your own parsing macro or directive which does something like:

```
#macro(include $templateName)
  #set($name = $templateName)
  #parse($templateName)
#end
```

Comment: And for the initial case, I can add the main file name to the VelocityContext object manually just before rendering. Thanks!